# How to "fill up" templated strings

Tags: c#

I would like to implement something like .NET's `decimal.ToString("###,###.00")` feature.

```
Template:      PR-00000
Data:          10
Output:        PR-00010
```

I don't know what this is called so researching didn't yield anything useful

EDIT: I've already found the solution but i'll expound further.

Composite formatting kind of gets things done, but my goal is to have the system as configurable as possible without being too technical. Seeing and entering the code template "Cat-0000" is more pleasing to non tech people.

Comment: It's called ["composite formatting"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting).  See also [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) and [Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings)

Comment: Cool! Got it to work. Thanks!

Comment: Write your answer below, not in the question.  Keep the Q&A separate.  You can then accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
int data=10;
string value = String.Format("PR-{0}", data.ToString("D5"));
Console.WriteLine(value);
```

Output: 
PR-00010

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Amy for giving me the hint. Didn't expect it to be this simple

```
var userInput = 10;
var template = "PR-0000";
var catalogCode = userInput.ToString(template);
// Output: PR-0010
```